# Clear one dynamic control on each click and instead add another string from list

Tags: c#, user-controls

Why am I getting same list string element on each button click? I would say, it should create new textBox each time?
In this case how to clear **only** this control, and leave all other textBoxes already created on same form, and after clear it should add another string from list instead?

```
int counter = 0;
private void btnOkreni_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            txt.Text = izabrana[counter].Opis;
            Controls.Add(txt);
            txt.Show();
            counter++;
}
```

Comment: It is really unclear what you are trying to achive. But first of all, you are creating new textboxes on each button click, but they would probably be one in top of the other, as you are not setting their `Location`

Comment: @Pikoh I want to use same dynamic created txtBox but to clear it on each click and add new string from list in empty(at the moment) textbox. I have location and size set, but I made it simple here. and still I got that it will be on top of each other at the moment, I am trying to fix it, but it doesnt have to do anything with location(then I will set creation of new object only on first click). I hope this is helpful.

Comment: but that textbox should be created on click not on form load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now, but do You agree this is good way to do it?(You may read comments under the question for more clear vision of what I was trying to do)

```
int brojacOkretanje = 0;
private void btnOkreni_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (brojacOkretanje == 0)
   {
          TextBox txt = new TextBox();
          txt.Name = "txtBoxOpis";
          txt.Text = izabrana[brojacOkretanje].Opis;
          Controls.Add(txt);
          txt.Location = new Point(41, 150);
          txt.Multiline = true;
          txt.Height = 82;
          txt.Width = 310;
          txt.Show();
    }
    else
    {
          TextBox txt = Controls.Find("txtBoxOpis", true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
          txt.Text = izabrana[brojacOkretanje].Opis;
    }

      brojacOkretanje++;
}
```